# undefined method `find_post' for #<PostsController:0x0000010b791560>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is where i got stuck in my code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end 

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end    

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def post_find
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

end
```

I defined post_find but i am still getting error when i run code sorry for the mistakes in post i am new to rails.  I want to be able to post on the forum and make edits or delete post.

Comment: Can you explain the context of your app and add the errors?

Comment: You defined a method post_find but trying to call find_post

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
def find_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

You defined your callback as `:find_post` but your method definition was `post_find`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `:post_find` like

```
before_action :post_find, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Because your method is `post_find`

```
 def post_find
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end
```

I think help you